# I have a pip package include version, how can I get delimiter

Tags: bash, awk

PIP packages example:

1. wheel==0.37.1
2. ansible==0.29.10
3. setuptools<45

Need to get exactly delimiter to verify installed package opposite required package:

wheel==0.37.1 output "="

setuptools<45  output "<"

Please help

Comment: Where do you get the pip packages from? A single file?

Comment: I have a requirement file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do (where `file` contains all 3 of your posted sample input lines just for testing with)?

```
$ grep -Eo '[<=]+' file
==
==
<
```

---

Original guesses:

```
$ awk -F'[<=]+' '{print $1}' file
wheel
ansible
setuptools

$ awk -F'[<=]+' '{print $2}' file
0.37.1
0.29.10
45
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
var1="wheel==0.37.1"
var2="setuptools<45"
echo $var1 | grep -Eo '[<=]+' OUTPUT "=="
echo $var2 | grep -Eo '[<=]+' OUTPUT "<"
```

Comment: Can you give more context and explain your answer and please if you post code post it as code block